# Autolayout side by side content

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

Hello I am new to IOS and learning the `autoLayout`. I need help to set the loader on the button accurately for all the screen sizes

[image]

The loader/spinner is displaying behind "Login". I want to show the loader at this position for all the devices. I know its an easy question but please could you tell me how can I do that using IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

control drag from the spinner to the button. add a horizontal spacing between the button and the spinner, then add "center vertically" between them and it should keep the spinner at a fixed distance from the login button and center aligned to the button

[image: autolayouts]
[image]

Comment: that didn't work. it is showing loader on top of button title

Comment: @hellosheikh does it look like in the image ive linked?

Comment: I think you are missing something. you see the blue background in image. Thats the whole button. and loader is on the button and  just behind the button title.

Comment: oh i see, didnt realise the whole thing was the button, so you want it aligned to the text and not the button itself. that does make it a bit harder. might be easier to not have the button having text, but rather make a separate label instead that is in the same place under the button, then align the loader to the label. ill see if i can work something out

Comment: ok ive solved it, click on the horizontal spacing width like in the 2nd picture, then change the first item to Button.Center.X, then the spinner will keep a fixed distance from the center of the button. the only problem is its not actually aligned to the text, so if the text changes it wont move, but maybe this wont affect you

Comment: I don't know how it is showing center x on your image. Mine is showing center Y after applying your constraints. constraints which you posted first

Comment: it would only show that if it was a vertical spacing constraint, make sure its a horizontal one aka "trailing space" and not "top space"

Comment: are you sure you are clicking on the trailing space constraint then? if you clicked on the Vertical Align / Align Center Y one, that would have the Button.Center.Y option.

Comment: where is the trailing space constraint. I am clicking this one "Indicator.centerY = Login Button Outlet.centerY"

Comment: there is no other constraint with the name of indicator

Comment: ye that is the wrong one, just double click on the `trailing space to: button` one on the right panel like in the first picture, then it should bring up the right menu where you can select Button.Center.X like in the 2nd picture. this is prob easier then actually trying to click on the constraint i guess

Comment: http://imgur.com/CjkGHrL 
see now it has moved the spinner to the right at the end

Comment: change the constant so its in the right place, eg 35

Answer (score 0):

to set layout constraint so that loader should be at center-vertically on button.
1. Select loader, right click hold and drag on button. Now release click
2. From options, select center vertically.

It will place your loader center vertically on button.

Now give set horizontal spacing of loader to login button, so that it should be at fixed distance from right/left corner.
3. Select loader, right click hold and drag on button to left/ right direction. Now release click.
4.  From options, select Horizontal spacing. It set fixed distance of loader 
from left/ right corner of button